# Blueimp Image Gallery: More than one Gallery getting Collapsed

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, blueimp

```
I am using Blueimp Image Gallery Library to create my gallery. I am having multiple galleries across several pages.

<div id="bangles">
    <a href="images/banles.jpg" title="banles" data-gallery>
        <img src="images/thumbnails/banles.jpg" alt="banles">
    </a>
    <a href="images/banles1.jpg" title="bangles1" data-gallery>
        <img src="images/thumbnails/banles1.jpg" alt="banles">
    </a>
    <a href="images/banles2.jpg" title="banles2" data-gallery>
    <img src="images/thumbnails/banles2.jpg" alt="banles">
    </a>
</div>


<div id="florals">
    <a href="images/florals.jpg" title="florals" data-gallery>
        <img src="images/thumbnails/florals.jpg" alt="florals">
    </a>
    <a href="images/florals1.jpg" title="florals1" data-gallery>
        <img src="images/thumbnails/florals1.jpg" alt="florals">
    </a>
    <a href="images/florals2.jpg" title="florals2" data-gallery>
    <img src="images/thumbnails/florals2.jpg" alt="florals">
    </a>
</div>
```

Here is my sample code. while i am trying open image gallery images collapsed across all.

I want to view each gallery in each page.

How do acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply modify your data-gallery tag with each gallery `parent-ID`

for eg:
you have 2 gallery in your post, those id's are `florals` and `bangles`
so you can modify `data-gallery` inside `gallery` preceded by `#blueimp-gallery`

1)  `<a data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery-bangles">`

2)  `<a data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery-florals">`

now you can able to open each gallery as you want.

Check out the [Documentation on Github](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery#container-ids-and-link-grouping)